# System.IndexOutOfRangeException: There is no row at position 0

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, indexoutofrangeexception

I am getting the following error when I click on the login button:

> There is no row at position 0

Specifically from the  `Image3.ImageUrl = HDT.Rows[0]["image"].ToString();` line.

Here is the db snapshot of the Society Table:

[image: Table-Society Snapshot]

The row is not null clearly, so what is the error about? What is position 0 exactly

Here is the block of code where i am getting error :

```
DS_HOUSE.HOUSE_SELECTDataTable HDT = new DS_HOUSE.HOUSE_SELECTDataTable();
DS_HOUSETableAdapters.HOUSE_SELECTTableAdapter HAdapter = new 
DS_HOUSETableAdapters.HOUSE_SELECTTableAdapter();

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   UDT = UAdapter.Select_By_UID(Convert.ToInt32(Session["uid"].ToString()));
   HDT = HAdapter.Select_By_SNAME_BLOCKNO(UDT.Rows[0]["societyname"].ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(UDT.Rows[0]["Houseid"].ToString()));
   Image3.ImageUrl = HDT.Rows[0]["image"].ToString();
   lblsname.Text = HDT.Rows[0]["sname"].ToString();
   lblbno.Text = HDT.Rows[0]["blockno"].ToString();
   lbltype.Text = HDT.Rows[0]["type"].ToString();
   ViewState["HID"] = HDT.Rows[0]["HID"].ToString();
}
```

Also i tried putting the code within if block with

```
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
         if (HDT.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        lblsell.Text = "";
        UDT = UAdapter.Select_By_UID(Convert.ToInt32(Session["uid"].ToString()));
        HDT = HAdapter.Select_By_SNAME_BLOCKNO(UDT.Rows[0]["societyname"].ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(UDT.Rows[0]["Houseid"].ToString()));

        {
            Image3.ImageUrl = HDT.Rows[0]["image"].ToString();
            lblsname.Text = HDT.Rows[0]["sname"].ToString();
            lblbno.Text = HDT.Rows[0]["blockno"].ToString();
            lbltype.Text = HDT.Rows[0]["type"].ToString();
            ViewState["HID"] = HDT.Rows[0]["HID"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

I was able to login however i was unable to retrieve details from the Society table.

[Snapshot of Society details not being retrieved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6wA7.png)

Comment: "What is position 0 exactly ?" - it's the first row, which you're from `HDT`. Note that checking for `HDT.Rows.Count` *before* populating `HDT` is odd, and won't help when `HAdapter.Select_By_SNAME_BLOCKNO` returns an empty table. (It's not clear why you have an extra block in that second code example either.)

Comment: What if the **query** returns an empty set?

Comment: `UDT.Rows[0]["societyname"]` still throws exceptions if `UDT.Rows.Count == 0`

Comment: i tried adding if (HDT.Rows.Count > 0)
after HAdapter.Select_By_SNAME_BLOCKNO ,still the same result

Comment: I very much doubt that, to be honest. I suggest you log the count just before you try to use the first row.

Comment: how do you do that ?sorry i am only beginner in this topic.

Comment: What is the value of `Session["uid"]`? What is the value of the UDT societyname that was retrieved? What is the row that you expect for that society?

Comment: uid is auto increment primary key,society name is Sname in the table and the 1st row should be retrieved which is Lubrizol society. But notihng is being displayed.Is there any way i can send whole source code so it can be solved faster ?

Comment: You checked with `if` **before** you filter the rows. Do it after and please do a step-by-step debugging session...

Comment: i added the if after HDT statement and yet Society details were not retrieved

Comment: You call `UAdapter.Select_By_UID` and `HAdapter.Select_By_SNAME_BLOCKNO` with some parameters. Are the values of those parameters what you expect? Do a `int uid=Convert.ToInt32(Session["uid"]);` before the first call and inspect (using the debugger) what the value of that `uid` is. The same for all other params.

Answer (score 0):

Place a breakpoint on the following line and debug:

```
Image3.ImageUrl = HDT.Rows[0]["image"].ToString();
```

Then, view the value of **HDT** in quick watch, when breakpoint hits above line.

Also, the if check `if (HDT.Rows.Count > 0)` should be placed right above `Image3.ImageUrl = HDT.Rows[0]["image"].ToString();`

After the **HDT** gets populated, that is.

It looks like **HDT** itself is not getting populated.

Comment: how do you view the value exactly? i added the breakpoint at that line but i am unable to view value through quick watch

Comment: Check out this MSDN article that walks through "Watch": https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0taedcee.aspx

Comment: I tried debugger ,it says the table Select_By_SNAME_BLOCKNO has count meaning no rows,but when i execute the procedure Select_By_SNAME_BLOCKNO it returns values ,so what is going wrong here

Comment: after placing the breakpoint on "Image3.ImageUrl = HDT.Rows[0]["image"].ToString(); " and hitting the breakpoint, right click and go to quick watch and in the textbox in quickwatch, type  HDT.Rows[0]["image"]. See if it returns a value

Answer (score 0):

It is apparent from your description that HDT is not null, but HTD.Rows is an empty collection, so element 0 does not exist.

Comment: so what changes do you suggest ?